# how to get a snapshot of video from url in java?

Tags: java, html, react-native, html5-video

how to get a snapshot of a video from URL in Java. Are there any libs for me or other ways like javaScript or html5 to make this possible?

Comment: want Java first.

Comment: so is your Video is stored in particular URL?

Comment: @sForSujit   user upload or any other video source URL.

Comment: Are you looking for multiple snapshots or single ?

Comment: @sForSujit  a single.

Comment: Okay, I know how we can take snapshot for video source URL, But i dont know about uploading and then taking snapshot .I f you wish I can put it in answer

Comment: @sForSujit   yes, thank you, I want to get the answer take a snapshot for video source URL.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this by using an API provided by [GrabzIt](https://grabz.it/about/), They provide API's for taking snapshots for Java, PHP, Javascript, Ruby, Python, ASP.NET, Node.js, Perl etc.

All we have to do is create an account on GrabzIt and once you create it, they will provide you an **Application Key** & **Application secret**. So now we just have to call an API's using the key & secret.

As this is Java question, I will keep with the java. So I am using Maven project to add the dependencies. So in pom.xml, add the dependency as:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>it.grabz.grabzit</groupId>
       <artifactId>grabzit</artifactId>
       <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Java class to call the API's

```
package com.sujit;

import it.grabz.grabzit.GrabzItClient;

public class Screenshot {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        GrabzItClient grabzIt = new GrabzItClient("Your Application Key", "Your application secret");
        grabzIt.URLToImage("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2uF2HuIful4"); // this will be video source URL
        String filepath = "D://Screeshots/result.jpg";  //this will be location, where you will save the snapshots
        grabzIt.SaveTo(filepath);
        System.out.println("done");
    }
}
```

**Note 1:** For demo purpose, I am saving the snapshot with the same name. But you will need a unique name for every snapshot. Otherwise, they will overwrite.

**Note 2:** As for the free account, you can take up to 1000 snapshots only. So for unlimited snapshots, you may need to upgrade account.

That's it. Thank you. Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: well, I think I don't have the ability to pay for this. I just want an open source for saving this problem in my project.

Comment: @BenD Ohhh i see, give me some time, I will update the answer with Open source API's

Comment: I found a way to solve this, but something error happened like this [link](http://android.techjaffa.xyz/tag/url-into-ffmpegframegrabber-load-video/)              could you help me if any way to solve this?

Comment: @BenD I don't understand anything in that link